# Access to the other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, models

I am trying getting it to work. I made proper associations and it still fails. Take a look at my code.

## post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :content

  before_create :format_content

  validates :content, presence:true, length: {minimum:21}

  def format_content
    profil = self.user.profile
    if profil.gender == "Mężczyzna"
      "Wiadomość od spottera: #{self.content}"
    elsif profil.gender == "Kobieta"
      "Wiadomość od spotterki: #{self.content}"
    end
  end
end
```

## post_spec.rb

```
describe "Properly formats content" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    let!(:poscik) {FactoryGirl.create(:post) }
    before(:each) {user.create_profile!(gender: "Kobieta", email: "donatella@dostojnie.pl")}
```

## rspec_failures

```
Post creation valid should have content Failure/Error: poscik = user.posts.create(content: "Weird #{"a"*25}") NoMethodError: undefined method `gender' for nil:NilClass
```

How to properly access other classes in models and why it doesn't find my method? I understand the error message - it says that my profile class wasn't defined

---

## user factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) {|i|"maestro#{i}@dot.pl"}
    password "kravmaga1290"
    association :profile, factory: :profile, strategy: :build
  end
end
```

Comment: code smell: `profil.gender == "Mężczyzna"`, it's not the problem of `Post`, create dedicated methods

Comment: What type of dedicated methods?

Comment: in profile: `def male?; gender == "Mężczyzna"; end`. In post: `if profile.male?`

Comment: other code smell: `format_content ` is to be used in view I guess. So it should live in a presenter, not in model

Comment: That's helpful thanks

Comment: So it also should be checked in integration tests, not unit tests, right?

Comment: integration specs should not worry about db, just about resulting pages

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you havent created an object of a class `Profile`. I think it is complaining about nil class that you are calling to get profile.gender.

Try in factories to add something like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.after_build do |user|
    user.profile ||= Factory.build(:profile, :user => user)
  end
end
```

And of course, you have to define profile factory as well.
Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `self.user.profile` in the Post model, the user that it finds does not have a profile associated with it. You should be able to setup the association within your FactoryGirl definition for the User class.